# Excel - Loop through rows and reverse order

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I was looking for a code that loop through all rows (I got too many), and change order for every three rows. I have a form of rows like this...
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld1kY.png)

Need to loop through all rows in column `B` and reverse order for every three rows and get this (for better analysis). Thank you

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMihq.png)

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Verify [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, type this formula into a cell in column `B` and drag down as far as necessary:

```
= INDEX(A:A,ROW()+2*(1-MOD(ROW()-1,3)))
```

VBA is not needed. This formula copies the values from column `A` to column `B`, but reverses the order of the entries every three rows as shown in your example image from your question.

See below.

[image]